# nested if statement runs correctly without else statement, but when the else statement is added it skips my if

Tags: c#, if-statement, datagridview

I am making up some code to select a row in a datagridview based on input of a textbox. works great without the else statement attached. but once the else statement is added on it isnt reading my if or just skipping it. i can type in the same number with and without the else statement and it will succeed or fail based on if the else statement is there. just not too sure where im going wrong.

```
 private void transactionSerial_Box_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string serialSearch = transactionSerial_Box.Text;
        int rowIndex = -1;

        if (transactionSerial_Box.Text.Length == 4)
        {
            DataRow matchingSerials = tooldataSet.Tool.Rows.Find(serialSearch);
           


            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in toolDataGridView.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(serialSearch))
                {
                    toolDataGridView.ClearSelection();
                    rowIndex = row.Index;
                    toolDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Serial number '" + serialSearch + "' is not a valid serial number. Please try again.", "invalid serial number", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    transactionSerial_Box.Text = "";
                    rowIndex = 0;
                    toolDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = false;
                    break;
                }
               
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: break in else will exit the loop and will not move over all rows

Comment: once i get the error once though, i would like to break out and reset a few things. i dont want it to give me 10 pop ups saying the same thing

Comment: bool isFound = false; then loop, inside loop if equal set isFound to true, after loop if isFound == false put the else code

Comment: I'm having a heck of time understanding your comment. could you elaborate for me please. the wording is hard to follow.

Comment: Use your `rowIndex=-1` as an indicator. The loop would look something like `foreach(row) { if (row.Value==serial) { rowIndex=row.Index; break; } }`. Then outside the loop you check `if (rowIndex==-1) { not found! } else { found! }`

Comment: thank you for clarification will give it a go. makes sense now!